# Facebook new feed API access

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm currently building an Android app that makes use of the Facebook API. I've gotten to the stage where I want to be able to retrieve a user's Newfeed i.e. the one you see at `https://www.facebook.com/home.php`. It seems that was possible using the `/{user-id}/home` endpoint but of course, that's now depreciated and they suggest using `/{user-id}/feed` but it seems entirely different since the `home` endpoint states

> returns posts a person sees in their News Feed

however the `feed` endpoint states

> links published by this person, or by others on this person's profile

which suggests the user's timeline instead.

Was that the only was of retrieving the newfeed? And is there any new endpoint I can use? I've tried looking already but it seems getting the user's newsfeed is no longer possible, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `feed`. It's basically a replacement for `home`, but yes, it only gets the posts they are tagged in and such that would appear on their timeline.

They removed the functionality you're looking for when they removed `home`.

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed).

Comment: Ah yes I thought so. Ah well, that's a project out the window. Thanks.

Comment: @PairedPrototype It does, they removed the functionality you're looking for. Kind of a shame.

Comment: Much agreed! It seems what I'm wanting is only limited to platforms that is without a Facebook app, and then it has to be verified by them.